# Alias uppercasing with Dapper

Tags: .net, oracle, dapper

I have the following query performed over `OracleConnection` (latest odp.net.managed package).

> const string sql = @"select MyCol, count(1) **Count** from T group by MyCol";
>
> dynamic[] rows = DB.Query(sql).ToArray();

It runs fine, however resulting dynamics have second property named as **COUNT**. 
Why? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose your alias in double quotes and oracle preserves whatever the case you specify.

```
const string sql = @"select MyCol, count(1) ""Count"" from T group by MyCol";
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `""` for escaping double quotes in a verbatim (`@`) string?